# i managed to create a MDNavigation drawer that goes to deferent screens. the problem is I don't want the drawer to appear on the first screen

Tags: python, kivy, navigation-drawer, screen, kivymd

if you slide the screen to the right the navigation drawer will appear on the signin screen, l don't want the drawer to appear at all on signin screen. the code is mainly in .kv is there a way to separate navigation drawer from signin screen. would appreciate the help i am learning kivy and kivymd.

```
kv file

<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    MDNavigationDrawerMenu:
        MDNavigationDrawerHeader:`
title: "Admin"
            title_font_size: '15sp'

        MDNavigationDrawerDivider:

        MDNavigationDrawerItem:
            icon: "point-of-sale"
            text: "New Sale"
            on_press: 
                app.root.ids.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                root.screen_manager.current = 'newsale'

        MDNavigationDrawerItem:
            icon: "sale"
            text: "Manage Sales"

     


MDScreen:
    MDNavigationLayout:
        MDScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager
            SignIn:                      # i dont want the drawer to appear on singIn
            NewSale:

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            radius: (0, 16, 16, 0)
            size_hint_x: 0.8

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer

#Design for first screen
<SignIn>:
    name:'signin'
    FloatLayout:
        MDTextField:
            hint_text:'Enter Username'
            icon_right: 'android'
            pos_hint: {'x':0.1, 'y': 0.7}
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 250

        MDTextField:
            hint_text:'Password'
            pos_hint: {'x':0.1, 'y': 0.5}
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 250

        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: 'login'
            pos_hint: {'x':0.5, 'y': 0.3}
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'newsale'

#design for second screen
<NewSale>:
    name:'newsale'
    FloatLayout:
        MDTopAppBar:
            title:''
            pos_hint: {'top': 1}
            left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: app.root.ids.nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
            right_action_items: [['tag', lambda x: app.root.ids.nav_drawer.set_state("open")],['dots-vertical', lambda x: app.root.ids.nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: 'Back'
            pos_hint: {'x':0.5, 'y': 0.5}
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'signin'
```

#python

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.scrollview import MDScrollView
from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import MDNavigationDrawer, MDNavigationLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window


Window.size = (300,500) #minimized to phone sized screen

class SignIn(MDScreen):
    pass

class NewSale(MDScreen):
    pass


sm = MDScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(SignIn(name='signin'))
sm.add_widget(NewSale(name='newsale'))


class ContentNavigationDrawer(MDScrollView):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue" 
        return
    
    def navigation_draw(self):
        print("navigation")
    
MainApp().run()
```